# User only upload own image to profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, cancan

I am having trouble implementing the gems cancan, with devise and carrierwave onboard rails 3.2.

Currently, I want users to be only able to upload images to their own user page (show). At the moment I have a users index page with all registered users. I can go into each of these and add an image to each profile with just a user role (not admin). I only want to be able to this for my own profile and effectively only be able to read other profile pages (minus the Add Photo link). My code is below:

```
   class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    # Define abilities for the passed in user here. For example:
    #


       user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
       if user.has_role? :user
       can :read, User
       can [:new, :create] , Photo, user_id: user.id
       end
  end
```

---

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

      before_filter :authenticate_user!


      def index
        @users = User.all
      end

        def show
          @user = User.find(params[:id])
          @photo = Photo.new(params[:user_id])
        end
    end
```

### EDITS TO CONTROLLER WITH AUTHORIZE!

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def new

    @photo = Photo.new(:user_id => params[:user_id])
    authorize! :new, @photo
  end

  def create

    @photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])
    if @photo.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created photo."
      redirect_to @photo.user
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
    authorize! :create, @photo
  end

  def edit
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    authorize! :update, @user
    if @photo.update_attributes(params[:photo])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated photo."
      redirect_to @photo.user
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    authorize! :destroy, @user
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    @photo.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed photo."
    redirect_to @photo.user
  end
end
```

---

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130512100231) do

  create_table "photos", :force => true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.string   "image"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "roles", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "resource_id"
    t.string   "resource_type"
    t.datetime "created_at",    :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    :null => false
  end

  add_index "roles", ["name", "resource_type", "resource_id"], :name => "index_roles_on_name_and_resource_type_and_resource_id"
  add_index "roles", ["name"], :name => "index_roles_on_name"

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          :default => 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                             :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             :null => false
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "avatar"
    t.string   "image"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], :name => "index_users_on_reset_password_token", :unique => true

  create_table "users_roles", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "role_id"
  end

  add_index "users_roles", ["user_id", "role_id"], :name => "index_users_roles_on_user_id_and_role_id"

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what CanCan is for. You've got it installed, but you haven't configured it.

`can :manage, Photo, user_id: user.id`

See also: [the manual](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities)

Additionally, you need to make sure you're calling `authorize!` in each controller action where you want access limited. For example:

`authorize! :create, @photo`

I prefer to use [`authorize_resource` or `load_and_authorize_resource`](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Authorizing-controller-actions) to make sure I haven't missed any actions, but just using `authorize!` will require the fewest changes to your code.

Comment: I have tried this over and over... with different configurations and can't seem to come to a result. I tried the above...

Comment: Another thing, I have tried using the console to find all users with the user role and only comes up with the admin. Could there be something wrong with my role registration?

Comment: I've read over and over the documentation... Is there something wrong with the association between photos and users. I cant see disable create/new photo on every user but the own users profile. I have edited above what im using in my ability.rb

Comment: Right now you're authorizing the ability to update or delete the __user__, not the ability to update the __photo__. Also you aren't authorizing the create action.

Comment: Ive done the edits for what I have currently based on your great advise. Its still not working however now I cant add photo to any profile, which is progress I guess... is there something im missing?

Comment: You're an absolute legend. My problem was that I wasnt putting the authorize! at the end of the controller methods..